# How do I implement server-side textbox and checkbox validation using PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I'm currently working on a program where I have to validate a form on the server-side using PHP. I've been able to write working validation code for  and  fields but I'm a bit stuck on some parts. I'm pretty new to coding and I'm not sure how to validate that a textbox contains a certain string using PHP. I've tried Googling but nothing seems to be working. Also, I need to verify a checkbox, where certain options from a dropdown only become active when a user checks the checkbox. I was sort of able to do this, but only after the user clicks the submit button were the changes applied. I need the changes to apply as soon as they click the checkbox.

I tried this for the textbox:

```
 $a = "June";
 $b = "July";
 if (empty($_POST[""])) {
    $textErr = "Text is required.";
} else if (!(preg_match("/{$a}/i", $text)) && (!preg_match("/{$b}/i", $text))){
    $textErr = "Text must contain either 'June' or 'July'.";
}
else {
    $text= test_input($_POST["text"]);
}
```

and also this:

```
$checkjune = stripos($_POST["text"], $a);
$checkjuly = stripos($_POST["text"], $b);

 (empty($_POST["text"])) {
    $textErr = "Text is required.";
} else if ($checkfl === false) {
    $textErr = "Text must contain either 'June' or 'July'.";
} else {
    $text = test_input($_POST["text"]);
}
```

This is kinda what I have currently for the checkbox:

(in HTML code)

```
 <div class="row">
                <input id="student" name="student" type="checkbox">I am a student</input>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="subject">Favorite Subject: </label>
                <select id="subject" name="subject" >
                    <option value="0" enabled>Not Applicable (I am not a student) </option>
                    <option value="1" disabled>Math</option>
                    <option value="2" disabled>Science</option>
                    <option value="3" disabled>English</option>
                   
                    <?php
                        if(!empty($_POST['student'])) {
                    echo "<script>document.getElementById('subject').disabled = ''; </script>";
                             }
                     ?>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: Immediate changes cannot be done with PHP. You'd have to utilize Javascript for that. And when you say that your textarea validation doesn't work, how exactly does it not work?

Comment: When I run it, the verification does not happen.

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't happen"? That's too vague. What do you expect to happen? To show the user a message? Is the message not showing?

Comment: Actually, I rechecked my code and there was a typo in that section. It appears to be working now. How would I implement that Javascript for the checkboxes? I'm not 100% sure. What I meant was the expected error message did not appear, but it's fine now.

Comment: Give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584514/how-to-disable-enable-form-elements-using-a-checkbox-with-javascript) a shot. @PetrFořtFru-Fru I'm not sure AJAX is needed here. I understood the OP as simply having to disable/enable a dropdown based on a checkbox.

Comment: Ok thank you both. I will go try that and see if I have more success.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood the question. You're right, you don't need AJAX, but just some JavaScript method, to enable a drop-down menu based on a checkbox. @El_Vanja